# Scrollviewer blocking events

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, routedevents

the thing i am battling today is the scrollviewer, and the fact that it blocks my events.SO..here's some xaml:

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollv" Panel.ZIndex="15" Margin="8,65.5,0,22" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="392.5" Background="White" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Grid x:Name="listaintrebari" Height="Auto" Width="301.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" >

        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

So the thing is: on  the grid which is inside the scrollviewer i programaticly add the questions UserControl...which incidentaly has a button with a click event.My problem is that i cant manage to click the button..it's like the scrollviewer is acting like an invisible shield to protect the usercontrol and the button from the evil Mouse!

Any help apreciated!

EDIT:(this is my questions Usercontrol)

```
   <UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:eHelper_v3"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="eHelper_v3.questions"
x:Name="IntrebareControl" Width="330.641" Margin="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="IntrebareControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"

>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,13,0" Height="90" >
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Panel.ZIndex="20" Height="90" Stroke="#FF0975A3"  >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#1404BFD8" Offset="0.004"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#1300A7FF" Offset="0.996"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#2B0F82CC" Offset="0.459"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Image x:Name="imagine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" Width="126.667" Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonDown="imagine_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textul" Margin="138.667,8,8,22.5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" FontSize="9.333"/>
    <Label x:Name="status" Content="Status" Height="22" Margin="127,0,100,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="9.333" Background="#00894848" Foreground="Red"/>
    <Button x:Name="raspundeBtn" Content="Raspunde" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="18" Margin="0,0,8,4.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50.974" FontSize="9.333" Click="raspundeBtn_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

REEDITED ...wrong code inserted...kinda sleepy over here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, some control ist in front of your button. To click "through" a control you can use

```
IsHitTestVisible="false"
```

Can you post your CommentThat ?

@after your edit:
It seems like your RichTextBox and that FlowDocument lies over the Button. 
Add your Button as the last child of your Grid.

Answer (score 0):

The user control is handling the left mouse button so the click does not get to the content.

```
    MouseLeftButtonDown="IntrebareControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"
```

Does that event get raised?

Comment: nothing gets raised.i have some messageboxes that should show up.but i dont get nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone also has problems with the ScrollViewer preventing mouse button events from firing, I solved this by setting a ZIndex for the corresponding UIElement:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World!" Panel.ZIndex="2" MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlockMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```